# Vibrate on push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

First of all I've checked all those links:

- [How to Call Vibrator inside a Service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005055/how-to-call-vibrator-inside-a-service-in-android)
- [Android notifications and vibrate from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230162/android-notifications-and-vibrate-from-service)
- [Android GCM turn on Lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195067/android-gcm-turn-on-lights)

But I can't achieve my phone vibrating when I receive a push notification. Here goes my code:

**PushReceiver**

```
public class PushReceiver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public PushReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null){
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            sendNotification(data.get("message"));
        }
        else{
            if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_done_all_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.str_notification_order_ready))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        notificationManager.notify(ConstantUtils.NOTIFICATION_ID_ORDER_READY, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**Testing**

> Device: Nexus 5
>
> Android version: 6.0.1

There is some kind of unknown sorcery that I should do to make it work?

Comment: You may want to check this SO [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36869888/5995040) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33951000/5995040). This might help you solve your issue.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I'm sorry for the delay to reply, but none of that solutions worked for me! :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use `setDefaults (int defaults)` to your `NotificationCompat.Builder` instance which provides you to default system sound, vibrate and lights for your notification.

The value should be **one** or more of the following fields combined with bitwise-or(|): [DEFAULT_SOUND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_SOUND), [DEFAULT_VIBRATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_VIBRATE), [DEFAULT_LIGHTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_LIGHTS).

For all default values, use [DEFAULT_ALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_ALL).

**Ex.** As per your code you are setting default sound so, if you want to set default sound and vibrate:

```
notificationBuilder.setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
```

If you want all default setting , you can achieve it by setting `notificationBuilder.setDefaults(-1)` , it consider as DEFAULT_ALL value.

See android [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)) for *setDefaults*.

**EDIT:**

The vibration  has a delay of 1000 ms. If you set the first one to 0, it will go off instantly. It's a { delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep } pattern

```
 // Each element then alternates between delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep
 notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
```

Comment: `setPriority()` works fine for sound and vibrate on devices which have `Oreo` but It wasn't working for `Pre-Oreo` ones. Using `setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE)` finally worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

This vibrates the phone:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
v.vibrate(500);
```

When you call the notification also call this

Comment: man I dont have any mContext inside my service, but I can call getSystemService without it, however, it keep not vibrating :(

Comment: mContext is the context, you can use `getActivity()` instead

Comment: For a service the context is the service itself. So you should be calling "this" for service